# CStatic Custom Control

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-c++, gdi, ownerdrawn

I am trying to create a custom `CStatic` control in `vc++` and have a few problems.

I originally was just using a `CStatic` control with the `SS_BLACKRECT` style. This was good for the situation until I needed to display an image over the control on demand.

I figured out all the logistics behind actually drawing the image onto the control but I cant seem to figure out how to do so without interfering with other things.

Basically I want the control to function as a normal `CStatic` with the `SS_BLACKRECT` style most of the time.

Then I need to be able to call a method that will cause it to draw an image over the control instead. I am doing the drawing using `GDI` and have tried it both in the `OnPaint()` method and the `DrawItem()` method without success. I can get it to draw in the `OnPaint()` but when I call the base **`CStatic::OnPaint()`** it draws over my image.

I need to be able to allow it to draw like normal but then just throw an image in on top. When I tried to do it in the `DrawItem()` method I had a problem because obviously it was not drawing using the `SS_BLACKRECT` style but waiting for me to draw the control like its supposed to.

I guess what I think I'm looking for is one of three things. A way to draw using `GDI` after the base `OnPaint()` method finishes. A way to have the control draw the default `SS_BLACKRECT` style and then `OWNERDRAW` the image afterwards. Or the code to mimic the drawing of `SS_BLACKRECT`.

The last one might be the easiest but I just don't know all the things I need to set up to draw a `CStatic` control like the default DrawItem.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `Default()` in your `OnPaint()` handler.

Then, depending on whether you're drawing your image, you can then draw over the top of the standard `CStatic` control.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple ideas:

If `CStatic::OnPaint()` draws over your image, then try calling it first and drawing your image afterwards.

Otherwise, from what little I've seen of SS_BLACKRECT, you should be able to replicate it's drawing simply be calling `CDC::FillSolidRect()` passing the rectangle of your control obtained through `GetClientRect()` and using the color returned by `GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWFRAME)`